# Allocation values from one row to another in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_one( person varchar(55), date_value date, proj varchar(2), value int, time varchar(2 ); 

INSERT INTO table_one VALUES 

('A1',2020-10-01'W',10,'T1')
('A1',2020-10-01'A',5,'T2')
('A1',2020-10-01'P',6,'T3')
('A1',2020-10-01'A',9,'T4')
('A1',2020-10-01'P',11,'T5')
('A1',2020-10-01'A',4,'T6')
('A1',2020-10-01'P',2,'T7')
('A1',2020-10-01'A',1,'T8')
('A1',2020-10-01'P',10,'T9')
('A1',2020-10-01'A',8,'T10')
```

I want an SQL query which creates a new column 'new_value'. The following are the conditions to fill that new column:

Case-1 When proj = A and next row proj = P , then take value of Proj=a in new_value column corresponding to proj=p.

For example, for row 2 the proj value is A and row 3 proj value is P. So the new column value correspoding to row-3 should be 5.

Case-2 When last row = A and the first row is W, then allocate value of last row in new_value column.

For example, row-10 has proj value A and row-1 has proj value W. So the new_value column correspoding to row-1 should be 8.

CASE-3 New_val should be NULL when proj = A.

Refer to the following picture for visual help

[image]

the above query needs to be aggregated at person,date_value column.

Comment: Is this mysql or snowflake? You have tags for both. Also, when you write `Case-1 When proj = A and next row`... How is the "next row" defined? Tables in storage have no order. How do you order the rows? The date column is always the same date. Is the order for the logic the order the rows appear in a file?

Comment: Ahh right! We have a time column too. That can be used to order by

Comment: added the column for order by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the sample data TIME column from varchar to int. The reason is that strings won't sort right. In string comparisons, '10' < '9'.

CREATE TABLE TABLE_ONE( person varchar(55), date_value date, proj varchar(2), value int, time int);

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_ONE VALUES 
('A1','2020-10-01','W',10,1),
('A1','2020-10-01','A',5,2),
('A1','2020-10-01','P',6,3),
('A1','2020-10-01','A',9,4),
('A1','2020-10-01','P',11,5),
('A1','2020-10-01','A',4,6),
('A1','2020-10-01','P',2,7),
('A1','2020-10-01','A',1,8),
('A1','2020-10-01','P',10,9),
('A1','2020-10-01','A',8,10)
;


select *, 
        case
            when PROJ = 'P' and lag(PROJ) over (partition by PERSON order by DATE_VALUE, TIME) = 'A' then 
                lag(VALUE) over (partition by PERSON order by DATE_VALUE, TIME)
            when row_number() over (partition by PERSON order by DATE_VALUE, TIME) = 1 and
                 last_value(PROJ) over (partition by PERSON order by DATE_VALUE, TIME) = 'A' then
                 last_value(VALUE) over (partition by PERSON order by DATE_VALUE, TIME)
        end as NEW_VALUE
from TABLE_ONE order by DATE_VALUE, TIME;
```

| PERSON | DATE_VALUE | PROJ | VALUE | TIME | NEW_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | W | 10 | 1 | 8 |
| A1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | A | 5 | 2 | null |
| A1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | P | 6 | 3 | 5 |
| A1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | A | 9 | 4 | null |
| A1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | P | 11 | 5 | 9 |
| A1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | A | 4 | 6 | null |
| A1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | P | 2 | 7 | 4 |
| A1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | A | 1 | 8 | null |
| A1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | P | 10 | 9 | 1 |
| A1 | 2020-10-01 00:00:00 | A | 8 | 10 | null |

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT person,date_value,proj,value,
lag(proj) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY person order by row_num) last_proj,
lag(value) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY person order by row_num) last_proj_value,
last_value(proj) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY person order by row_num) person_last_proj,
first_value(proj) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY person order by row_num) person_first_proj,
last_value(value) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY person order by row_num) person_last_proj_value,
CASE 
  WHEN proj='P' AND last_proj = 'A' THEN last_proj_value --Case_1
  WHEN person_last_proj = 'A' AND person_first_proj = 'W' AND row_num = 1 THEN person_last_proj_value --case_2
  WHEN proj='A' THEN NULL --CASE_3
  ELSE NULL
END AS New_value
FROM 
(SELECT person,date_value,proj,value,row_number() over (partition by person order by date_value) as row_num
FROM table_one);
```